# Ext.Net - Conversion element type ComboBox

Tags: ext.net

I have ComboBox with а few items. Default returned type of item's value - String. I would like to know how can I get 'Int' type of value of selected item in ComboBox.

Explicit conversion produces an error: Specified cast is not valid.

Thanks!:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use int.Parse(box.SelectedValue). If it gives you an error, it means that the value is not an integer. In that case, it may be that the value is empty, and only the text is set.

Comment: But: When this value using "sqlCommand.Parameters" I'm trying to write to the database, an error: Must declare the scalar variable "@ Room".
The code to add records to the database as follows:
String createRow = "INSERT INTO Contact (Room) VALUES (@Room)";
myCommand = new SqlCommand(createRow, MyConnection);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sRoom", int.Parse(ComboBox1.SelectedItem.Value));

Comment: Pay attention that the parameter you adding has the name sRoom instead of Room. Delete the 's' and I believe it should work.

Comment: It works, damn it. Indeed, I have not seen too much s. Thank you)

Comment: So, very strange, when I added record, in database showed value of column "Room" - NaN. But in ComboBox was value '20'...